# How do I get my laptop to work at Wireless N speed?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I have a Tenda WAP which has two attenas. Which I'm told means with it transfer wireless N and the slower speed. It's a Tenda W300D Wireless-N ADSL3+ Modem Router.

I've just bought a Tenda wireless N USB adapter 300mbps Model W322U V2.o.

However I can not get my laptop with the usb adapter to connect above 54.0 mbps, it has an excellent connection and I've tried moving my laptop next to my wap.

I've tried various settings and spoke to my local computer shop, but I can' get the higher speed.

I'm trying to get the higher speed for better LAN speeds.

Heres my settings... Can someone tell me when my problem is ?

Theres are my wap settings
[image]

Heres my basic card settings

[image]

Heres my usb stick settings

[image]

Edit : Added Wap model

Comment: Can you tell us the specific model of your router/WAP?

Comment: I can't find the source but I read that WiFiN @300Mbps requires WPA2 encryption. WIll update once I can find the source

Comment: @Sathya that is true http://blogs.techworld.com/war-on-error/2009/10/fast-wi-fis-little-secret---you-have-to-turn-on-wpa2-encryption/

Comment: OK, I'll try that. But why doesn't WPA2 require a password ? Should I go for the WPA2-PSK instead ?. I'd like to keep my long hex password, I notice theres also TKIP and AEs. Which settings should I use ?

Comment: OK I tried WPA2-personal wih TKIP and specified an 8 digit password and my connection speed was still 54.0mbps

Comment: @Jules - Are there any other computers/devices on the wireless LAN?

Comment: [5 Ways To Fix Slow 802.11n Speed](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-basics/30664-5-ways-to-fix-slow-80211n-speed)

Comment: Yes there are other devices on the WLAN, but my local computer shop that didn't matter as I had two attenas on my router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

802.11n speeds require AES (AES-CCMP) encryption.

Sathya was on the right track when he said WPA2, because WPA2 implies AES. However, many vendors support what the Wi-Fi Alliance calls "WPA2 Mixed Mode", which is actually WPA2(AES) plus WPA(TKIP) enabled at the same time.

It sounds like Jules snatched defeat from the jaws of victory when he configured WPA2 Mixed Mode on the AP, but then went and selected slow old TKIP on his otherwise N-capable client.

By the way, the authentication type (Personal/PSK vs. Enterprise/802.1X) doesn't matter. It's only the confidentiality cipher (AES-CCMP vs. TKIP) that matters.